# Looping email code

Tags: php, email, loops, smtp

I've been using the code below for years to send email from my site, but the problem is that it sends the mail many times sometimes.

Example: if I send a message to my users, some may get it 5 times, etc. even when I send to one person only, he may get it 3 times.

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "xxx Support <noreply@xxxx.com>";
$to = "$name <$email>";
$subject = "xxxxx";
$body = "xxx";

$host = "mail.xxx.com";
$username = "noreply+xxx.com";
$password = "xzcsd=sfd?hdssc";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
      }`
```

Comment: This code looks ok. Your problem may be in the way you loop over the mails or in how you get the e-mails from the database. Are you sure you're getting _unique_ e-mail addresses?

Comment: The error isn't obvious from this piece of code. Maybe it's somewhere higher up the codebase, at the piece that actually use this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to complicate your solution a bit to add tracking. For instance add a new table in your DB that has a record for each email sent.

The table structure may be something like

email_id (PK)
 email_source (FK to table including emails)
 user_id (FK to users table)

Then you can send the email to those users who did not receive this version of the email.

This can help you to off-load your SMTP, or send the email in bulks distributed over the day. As well this can help you to track the users who open the email, or interacted with the email.

Hope that helps.